# How can I get Perl's ref() function to return REF, IO, and LVALUE?

Tags: perl, types

The documentation for [ref()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) mentions several possible return values. I understand most of them, but not `REF`, `IO`, and `LVALUE`. How would I write Perl code to cause `ref` to return those values?

After reading the documentation on [typeglobs and file handles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), I came close for `IO` with this code:

```
open(INPUT, '<', 'foo.pl');
print ref(*INPUT{IO}), "\n";  # Prints IO::Handle
```

For `REF` and `LVALUE` I tried several bizarre constructions, but had no success.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way to produce most of them:

```
use 5.010;
say 'SCALAR:  ', ref \undef;
say 'ARRAY:   ', ref [1..5];
say 'HASH:    ', ref { key => 'value' };
say 'CODE:    ', ref sub {};
say 'REF:     ', ref \\undef;
say 'GLOB:    ', ref \*_;
say 'LVALUE:  ', ref \substr "abc", 1, 2;
say 'LVALUE:  ', ref \vec 42, 1, 2;
say 'FORMAT:  ', ref *STDOUT{FORMAT}; # needs declaration below
say 'IO:      ', ref *STDIN{IO};   # actually prints IO::Handle
say 'VSTRING: ', ref \v5.10.0;
say 'Regexp:  ', ref qr/./;

format =
.
```

REF is just a reference to another reference.  LVALUE is a special case of a scalar that has an external influence if it is modified.

IO is the base type behind the handles, you can make it appear explicitely using [Acme::Damn from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~ibb/Acme-Damn-0.02/Damn.pm).  As noted by Michael Carman in the comments, you really shouldn't be unblessing objects — don't use in real code.

```
use Acme::Damn;
say 'IO:      ', ref damn *STDIN{IO}; # really prints IO
```

The source for the `ref` function also has bits of code to display "BIND" and "UNKNOWN", but there shouldn't be a way to get those without messing with the internals.  Blead also has an interesting unblessed "REGEXP" (different from the "Regexp" above); if someone knows how to make `ref` yield that...

Comment: As delightful as the name `damn` is, it's unlikely that you'll want to remove the blessing. Use `Scalar::Util::reftype()` to see past the `bless` to the underlying reference type.

Comment: Damn! I forgot about Scalar::Util!  :-D  Unfortunately, I can't seem to use it to make `ref` return "IO".  I'll add a warning about `damn` not being serious; thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4):

`REF` means that you have a reference to a reference:

```
my ($x, $y, $z);
$x = 1;
$y = \$x;
$z = \$y;
print ref $z;  # REF
```

`LVALUE` refs are rare, but you can get them from certain functions that return lvalues. `substr` is one:

```
$x = 'abcdefg';
$y = \ substr($x, 0, 3);
print ref $y;  # LVALUE
```

`IO::Handle` objects are actually blessed `IO` refs:

```
$x = *STDIN{IO};
print ref $x;  # IO::Handle
print $x;      # IO::Handle=IO(0x12345678)
```

I'm not sure how to get an `IO` ref directly.

Answer (score 2):

1. `LVALUE`

   ```
   perl5.8 -e '{$a = "aaa"; $b = \substr($a, 0, 2); print "$$b\n"; print ref($b)."\n"}'
   ```

   ```
   aa
   ```

   `LVALUE`

   This one is explained in [`perldoc -f ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html)
2. `REF`

   ```
   perl5.8 -e '{$a = "aaa"; $b = \\$a; print ref($b)."\n"}'
   ```

   `REF`

   It's basically a reference to a value that is itself a reference.
   Probably would have been better to do `$b = \$a; $c = \$b; print ref($c)`