# How do I tell what type of value is in a Perl variable?

Tags: perl

How do I tell what type of value is in a Perl variable?

`$x` might be a scalar, a ref to an array or a ref to a hash (or maybe other things).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[ref()](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node62.html):

> Perl provides the `ref()` function so that you can check the reference type before dereferencing a reference...
>
> By using the `ref()` function you can protect program code that dereferences variables from producing errors when the wrong type of reference is used...

Comment: I thought ref() would only tell you what type of reference it is and return nothing if it isn't one.

Comment: @Chris:  Right, so if the variable is not a reference, you can infer that it is a simple scalar from the fact that it returns nothing.  Otherwise, you will know what kind of reference it is.

Comment: @pm100: You're absolutely welcome; perhaps you could edit your question saying what constraints you have?

Comment: @Adam: I guess I was thinking in more in general, but the OP did say $x (as opposed to @x or %x). So, you're right.

Comment: I think pm100's was talking about the 15 char comment constraint on SO.

Comment: Note that the guide this answer links to is unreliable. The table of return values has at least one error. I would not use it.

Answer (score 53):

`$x` is always a scalar. The hint is the sigil `$`: any variable (or dereferencing of some other type) starting with `$` is a scalar. (See [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for more about data types.)

A reference is just a particular type of scalar. 
The built-in function [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) will tell you what kind of reference it is. On the other hand, if you have a blessed reference, `ref` will only tell you the package name the reference was blessed into, not the actual core type of the data (blessed references can be hashrefs, arrayrefs or other things). You can use [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3A%3AUtil) 's `reftype` will tell you what type of reference it is:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(reftype);

my $x = bless {}, 'My::Foo';
my $y = { };

print "type of x: " . ref($x) . "\n";
print "type of y: " . ref($y) . "\n";
print "base type of x: " . reftype($x) . "\n";
print "base type of y: " . reftype($y) . "\n";
```

...produces the output:

```
type of x: My::Foo
type of y: HASH
base type of x: HASH
base type of y: HASH
```

For more information about the other types of references (e.g. coderef, arrayref etc), see this question: [How can I get Perl's ref() function to return REF, IO, and LVALUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399833/how-can-i-get-perls-ref-function-to-return-ref-io-and-lvalue) and [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Note: You should *not* use `ref` to implement code branches with a blessed object (e.g. `$ref($a) eq "My::Foo" ? say "is a Foo object" : say "foo not defined";`) -- if you need to make any decisions based on the type of a variable, use [`isa`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) (i.e `if ($a->isa("My::Foo") { ...` or `if ($a->can("foo") { ...`). Also see [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Comment: Note that reftype, by definition, violates encapsulation, so should be avoided unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: If you do use reftype, be aware that it returns undef for a non-reference, so code like `reftype($x) eq 'HASH'` may result in warnings.  (ref, on the other hand, conveniently returns '' for non-references.)

Comment: @ysth: quite so! I've updated my response.. it's rare to find a good use for `ref` on blessed objects.

Comment: (er, I meant to say `reftype` of course.) :) If one needs to access a blessed object directly, there should be an accessor method which abstracts away the implementation details.

Answer (score 25):

A scalar always holds a single element. Whatever is in a scalar variable is always a scalar. A reference is a scalar value.

If you want to know if it is a reference, you can use [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html). If you want to know the reference type,
you can use the `reftype` routine from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util).

If you want to know if it is an object, you can use the `blessed` routine from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util). You should never care what the blessed package is, though. `UNIVERSAL` has some methods to tell you about an object: if you want to check that it has the method you want to call, use `can`; if you want to see that it inherits from something, use `isa`; and if you want to see it the object handles a role, use `DOES`.

If you want to know if that scalar is actually just acting like a scalar but tied to a class, try [`tied`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tied.html). If you get an object, continue your checks.

If you want to know if it looks like a number, you can use `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util). If it doesn't look like a number and it's not a reference, it's a string. However, all simple values can be strings.

In v5.36, the `builtin` pragma has `created_as_number` and `created_as_string`, which really mean that the last thing that operator on the value was numeric or stringy. There's also `is_bool` to check if the values are the distinguished booleans `true` or `false` (and not just any true or false value in the normal Perl way).

If you need to do something more fancy, you can use a module such as [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Params-Validate).

Answer (score 6):

I like polymorphism instead of manually checking for something:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class Foo {
    use MooseX::MultiMethods;

    multi method foo (ArrayRef $arg){ say "arg is an array" }
    multi method foo (HashRef $arg) { say "arg is a hash" }
    multi method foo (Any $arg)     { say "arg is something else" }
}

Foo->new->foo([]); # arg is an array
Foo->new->foo(40); # arg is something else
```

This is much more powerful than manual checking, as you can reuse your "checks" like you would any other type constraint.  That means when you want to handle arrays, hashes, and even numbers less than 42, you just write a constraint for "even numbers less than 42" and add a new multimethod for that case.  The "calling code" is not affected.

Your type library:

```
package MyApp::Types;
use MooseX::Types -declare => ['EvenNumberLessThan42'];
use MooseX::Types::Moose qw(Num);

subtype EvenNumberLessThan42, as Num, where { $_ < 42 && $_ % 2 == 0 };
```

Then make Foo support this (in that class definition):

```
class Foo {
    use MyApp::Types qw(EvenNumberLessThan42);

    multi method foo (EvenNumberLessThan42 $arg) { say "arg is an even number less than 42" }
}
```

Then `Foo->new->foo(40)` prints `arg is an even number less than 42` instead of `arg is something else`.

Maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

At some point I read a reasonably convincing argument on Perlmonks that testing the type of a scalar with `ref` or `reftype` is a bad idea.  I don't recall who put the idea forward, or the link.  Sorry.

The point was that in Perl there are many mechanisms that make it possible to make a given scalar act like just about anything you want.  If you `tie` a filehandle so that it acts like a hash, the testing with `reftype` will tell you that you have a filehandle.  It won't tell you that you need to use it like a hash.

So, the argument went, it is better to use duck typing to find out what a variable is.

Instead of:

```
sub foo {
    my $var = shift;
    my $type = reftype $var;

    my $result;
    if( $type eq 'HASH' ) {
        $result = $var->{foo};
    }
    elsif( $type eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        $result = $var->[3];
    }
    else {
        $result = 'foo';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

You should do something like this:

```
sub foo {
    my $var = shift;
    my $type = reftype $var;

    my $result;

    eval {
        $result = $var->{foo};
        1; # guarantee a true result if code works.
    }
    or eval { 
        $result = $var->[3];
        1;
    }
    or do {
        $result = 'foo';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

For the most part I don't actually do this, but in some cases I have.  I'm still making my mind up as to when this approach is appropriate.  I thought I'd throw the concept out for further discussion.  I'd love to see comments.

**Update**

I realized I should put forward my thoughts on this approach.

This method has the advantage of handling anything you throw at it.

It has the disadvantage of being cumbersome, and somewhat strange.  Stumbling upon this in some code would make me issue a big fat 'WTF'.

I like the idea of testing whether a scalar **acts like** a hash-ref, rather than whether it is a hash ref.

I don't like this implementation.

Comment: I'm probably the one you're thinking about. I say never test against literal strings. Test against prototypes: if( ref $f eq ref {} ). As for tie, you start with tied(): if you get an object, do the normal stuff.

Comment: Please never, never actually test refs that way. It's so easy to do it easier. :)

Comment: brain, that's another interesting point--not the one I was thinking of.  I can see your point though.

Comment: Very interesting, but this is better suited for a discussion forum like clp.misc than SO.

Comment: @brian: what's wrong with testing against literal strings? The values `ref()` returns aren't going to change and it's clearer (at least arguably so). Moreover, how do you construct a prototype for things like SCALAR and GLOB references?

Comment: I don't like literal strings because people tend to type them incorrectly or misremember them. It's part of a more general issue of any "magic strings" as source code or constants. Since there is a way to do it without special knowledge of magic strings that, I do that.

Comment: If you think clp.misc is good for anything, you haven't been there in awhile. I already know what the five clueful people on that list will say, and two of them are permanantly killfilled. :)  Seriously though, I think SO is a fine place for this, although it probably deserves it's own question.

Comment: @Michael Carman: FWIW, the values ref returns historically *have* changed, but not in ways that brian d foy's suggestion would have helped with.

Comment: The acts-like test is great if you want to validate that, say, what you expect is a hashref is in fact one.  A series of ifs breaks the strength of this approach, which is to correctly handle multiple overloaded deref types.  (Though the auto-creation of subs makes acts-like-a-coderef tests impossible to do correctly, and pseudohashes used to be a problem too.)

Comment: The problem with "acts like" tests is that a tied variable might have side effects even for mere accesses. There are already ways to introspect the variable without actually doing anything with it.

Comment: @Michael: surely you know how to get a scalar and glob ref:  `ref \ ''` for scalar and `ref \*STDOUT` (or similar) for glob.

Comment: @daotoad.  I can't understand your function foo utilizing do block. can you explain how it works?

Comment: @programmingzeal, what part don't you understand? `eval` catches exceptions and each block will return true if it succeeds and false if it throws.  `or` is being used as a logical chain, it operates like `elsif` here, but has cleaner syntax.  The final `do` just bundles up a block of code into a single expression, much like an eval, it's there to let you cleanly finish up with a block rather than just the one line.  You could easily wind up with `or die "Nothing worked, brah\n";` or similar.