# How to get the type of the reference?

Tags: perl

Is there any function available in Perl to check the reference type:

```
my $ref=\@array;
```

I need to get the reference type as `array` by the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell what type of value is in a Perl variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731333/how-do-i-tell-what-type-of-value-is-in-a-perl-variable)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use function **ref**:

```
$ref_type = ref $ref;
```

The return value is the one of: **SCALAR**, **ARRAY**, **HASH**, **CODE** (reference to subprogram), **GLOB** (reference to **typeglob**) and **REF** (reference to reference).

Actually, **ref** function may return more values and in case of reference to object returns package name instead of type: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html.

Comment: Note the reference has been blessed, ref() returns the package name, not the underlying data-type. In such cases, you might consider using Scalar::Util's reftype and blessed methods.

Comment: @snoopy Though, most of the time it's more useful to know the package name (class) of the object. And you shouldn't be messing with the object internals manually anyway.