# How can I test that "something" is a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am receiving a hash of hashes from another function, and some elements of the hash of hashes can be another hash. How can I test to see if something is a hash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell what type of value is in a Perl variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731333/how-do-i-tell-what-type-of-value-is-in-a-perl-variable)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Depending on what you want you will need to use `ref` or `reftype` (which is in [`Scalar::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html), a core module).  If the reference is an object, `ref` will return the class of the object instead of the underlying reference type, `reftype` will always return the underlying reference type.

```
if (ref $var eq ref {}) {
   print "$var is a hash\n";
}

use Scalar::Util qw/reftype/;

if (reftype $var eq reftype {}) {
    print "$var is a hash\n";
}
```

Comment: @brian d foy  Are you unfamiliar with the word "tf"?  It is like "if", but more so.

Comment: So, a stronger version of if? Is there a weaker version too?

Comment: I thought **emphatic if** was "iiiif", or perlishly: `'i'x$n.'f'` (for $n > 1)

Comment: From [perldoc 'ref'](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html): _If the referenced object has been blessed into a package, then that package name is returned instead. But don't use that, as it's now considered "bad practice". For one reason, an object could be using a class called Regexp or IO , or even HASH . Also, ref doesn't take into account subclasses, like isa does.

Instead, use blessed (in the Scalar::Util module) for boolean checks, isa for specific class checks and [reftype](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#reftype) (also from Scalar::Util) for type checks._

Answer (score 20):

Use [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) function:

```
ref($hash_ref) eq 'HASH' ## $hash_ref is reference to hash
ref($array_ref) eq 'ARRAY' ## $array_ref is reference to array

ref( $hash{$key} ) eq 'HASH' ## there is reference to hash in $hash{$key}
```

Comment: This test doesn't work for hash-like objects: `$r={};bless $r,"fail";print ref $r`

Comment: There are also some false positives here. `$array = []; bless $array, 'HASH'; print ref $array;` prints `HASH`. Not that you should ever do this.

Answer (score 5):

I've always used `isa`, but if the thing being tested isn't an object (or might not be an object), you need to call it as the function `UNIVERSAL::isa` :

```
if ( UNIVERSAL::isa( $var, 'HASH' ) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use Params::Util qw<_HASH _HASH0 _HASHLIKE>;

# for an unblessed hash with data
print "$ref is a hash\n" if _HASH( $ref ); 
# for an unblessed hash empty or not
print "$ref is a hash\n" if _HASH0( $ref ); 
# for a blessed hash OR some object that responds as a hash*
print "$ref is hashlike\n" if _HASHLIKE( $ref );
```

* through [`overload`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload)

You probably do not need the last one, though.

see [`Params::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params%3a%3aUtil)

Comment: `Params::Util::_HASHLIKE` calls `Scalar::Util::reftype`, but it also checks to see if its argument is overloading the hash-dereferencing operator -- this detects objects that can pretend to be hashrefs  even when they are not really hashrefs.

Comment: @mobrule: Yeah, I know. I just thought presenting two choices would drive him to the link to see the difference. I added a note saying that he probably doesn't need it.