# When does ref($variable) return 'IO'?

Tags: perl, filehandle

Here's the relevant excerpt from the documentation of the [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) function:

> The value returned depends on the type of thing the reference is a reference to. Builtin types include:
>
> ```
> SCALAR
> ARRAY
> HASH
> CODE
> REF
> GLOB
> LVALUE
> FORMAT
> IO
> VSTRING
> Regexp
> ```

---

Based on this, I imagined that calling `ref` on a filehandle would return `'IO'`. Surprisingly, it doesn't:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fileHandle, '<', 'aValidFile';
close $fileHandle;

print ref $fileHandle;     # prints 'GLOB', not 'IO'
```

---

[`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) tries to explain why:

> It isn't possible to create a true
>   reference to an IO handle (filehandle
>   or dirhandle) using the backslash
>   operator. The most you can get is a
>   reference to a typeglob, which is
>   actually a complete symbol table
>   entry [...] However, you can still
>   use type globs and globrefs
>   as though they were IO handles.

---

In what circumstances would `ref` return `'IO'` then?

Comment: I don't think the `perlref` excerpt is completely relevant here, but it's the closest I could find.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399833/how-can-i-get-perls-ref-function-to-return-ref-io-and-lvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get an IO reference is to use the *FOO{THING} syntax:

```
$ioref = *glob{IO};
```

where glob is a named glob like STDIN or a reference like $fh.  But once you have
such a reference, it can be passed around or stored in arbitrary data structures just like any other scalar, so things like marshalling modules need to be savvy of it.

Since a glob or globref can be used as a filehandle and implicitly get the contained IO thingy, there isn't a lot of need for IO refs.  The main exception is this:

```
use Symbol;
# replace *FOO{IO} handle but not $FOO, %FOO, etc.
*FOO = geniosym;
```

(geniosym returns a new semi-anonymous IO reference, and any non-glob reference-to-glob assignment only assigns to that particular reference's part of the glob)

Answer (score 2):

As Konerak says, the answer is in this question:

[How can I get Perl's ref() function to return REF, IO, and LVALUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399833/how-can-i-get-perls-ref-function-to-return-ref-io-and-lvalue)

The relevant snippet is:

```
use Acme::Damn;
say 'IO:      ', ref damn *STDIN{IO}; # really prints IO
```

and this should not really be used in production code since damn removes the bless from the reference...

Comment: Hmm... Is this the only instance where `ref` would return `'IO'`?