# What is the best way to determine if a scalar holds a filehandle?

Tags: perl

I am trying to determine if a given scalar holds a filehandle.  It could have been passed to me from a bareword filehandle (i.e. `\*FH`), a lexical filehandle, an IO::Handle, an IO::File, etc.  So far, the only thing that seems to be consistent amongst the various flavors is that they all have a [`reftype`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#reftype-EXPR) of `"GLOB"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell what type of value is in a Perl variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731333/how-do-i-tell-what-type-of-value-is-in-a-perl-variable)

Comment: Oops sorry, that isn't an exact dupe.  I wish I could retract that close vote!  (But the link is still somewhat relevant.)

Comment: See [When does `ref($variable)` return 'IO'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955428/when-does-refvariable-return-io) for a similar question.

Comment: Is the purpose just to validate input arguments, or to provide different behavior based on variable types (e.g. open a file if a string is passed in)? Best thing to do might be to just treat it like a filehandle and throw an exception if it doesn't behave like one.

Comment: If it is a normal scalar I want to try to open a file with that name in the scalar, if it is already a filehandle I want to use the filehandle.

Comment: If you want to tell the difference between a filehandle and a string, I'd probably just use the same method as in File::Copy.

Comment: @runrig yeah, but what File::Copy is doing is very bad.  `UNIVERSAL::isa` breaks Classes that overload `isa`.

Comment: And using fileno() doesn't work for tied filehandles...there is no "good" solution. And read http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=615039 for one opinion on breaking isa in this situation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [openhandle](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#openhandle) function from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util):

> `openhandle FH`
>
> Returns FH if FH may be used as a
>   filehandle and is open, or FH is a
>   tied handle. Otherwise undef is
>   returned.
>
> ```
>   $fh = openhandle(*STDIN);           # \*STDIN
>   $fh = openhandle(\*STDIN);          # \*STDIN
>   $fh = openhandle(*NOTOPEN);         # undef
>   $fh = openhandle("scalar");         # undef
> ```

The current implementation is similar to [Greg Bacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214647/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-scalar-holds-a-filehandle/3214883#3214883), but it has some additional tests.

Answer (score 13):

Remember that you can do this:

```
$ perl -le '$fh = "STDOUT"; print $fh "Hi there"'
Hi there
```

That's an ordinary string but still useful as a filehandle.

Looking at the [source of `IO::Handle`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GBARR/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Handle.pm), its `opened` is a thin wrapper around [`fileno`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html), which has a handy property:

> Returns the file descriptor for a filehandle, or undefined if the filehandle is not open.

But there is one caveat:

> Filehandles connected to memory objects via new features of open may return undefined even though they are open.

It appears then that a test along the lines of

```
$@ = "";
my $fd = eval { fileno $maybefh };
my $valid = !$@ && defined $fd;
```

will do what you want.

The code below checks representatives of

- in-memory objects
- named filehandles
- globs
- glob references
- glob names
- the standard input
- `FileHandle` instances
- `IO::File` instances
- pipes
- FIFOs
- sockets

Run it yourself:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Fatal qw/ open /;
use FileHandle;
use IO::File;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $SLEEP = 5;
my $FIFO  = "/tmp/myfifo";

unlink $FIFO;
my $pid = fork;
die "$0: fork" unless defined $pid;
if ($pid == 0) {
  system("mknod", $FIFO, "p") == 0 or die "$0: mknod failed";
  open my $fh, ">", $FIFO;
  sleep $SLEEP;
  exit 0;
}
else {
  sleep 1 while !-e $FIFO;
}

my @ignored = (\*FH1,\*FH2);
my @handles = (
  [0, "1",           1],
  [0, "hashref",     {}],
  [0, "arrayref",    []],
  [0, "globref",     \*INC],
  [1, "in-memory",   do {{ my $buf; open my $fh, "<", \$buf; $fh }}],
  [1, "FH1 glob",    do {{ open FH1, "<", "/dev/null"; *FH1 }}],
  [1, "FH2 globref", do {{ open FH2, "<", "/dev/null"; \*FH2 }}],
  [1, "FH3 string",  do {{ open FH3, "<", "/dev/null"; "FH3" }}],
  [1, "STDIN glob",  \*STDIN],
  [1, "plain read",  do {{ open my $fh, "<", "/dev/null"; $fh }}],
  [1, "plain write", do {{ open my $fh, ">", "/dev/null"; $fh }}],
  [1, "FH read",     FileHandle->new("< /dev/null")],
  [1, "FH write",    FileHandle->new("> /dev/null")],
  [1, "I::F read",   IO::File->new("< /dev/null")],
  [1, "I::F write",  IO::File->new("> /dev/null")],
  [1, "pipe read",   do {{ open my $fh, "sleep $SLEEP |"; $fh }}],
  [1, "pipe write",  do {{ open my $fh, "| sleep $SLEEP"; $fh }}],
  [1, "FIFO read",   do {{ open my $fh, "<", $FIFO; $fh }}],
  [1, "socket",      IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => "localhost:80")],
);

sub valid {
  local $@;
  my $fd = eval { fileno $_[0] };
  !$@ && defined $fd;
}

for (@handles) {
  my($expect,$desc,$fh) = @$_;
  print "$desc: ";

  my $valid = valid $fh;
  if (!$expect) {
    print $valid ? "FAIL\n" : "PASS\n";
    next;
  }

  if ($valid) {
    close $fh;
    $valid = valid $fh;
    print $valid ? "FAIL\n" : "PASS\n";
  }
  else {
    print "FAIL\n";
  }
}

print "Waiting for sleeps to finish...\n";
```

All passes on an Ubuntu 9.10 box, so the caveat concerning in-memory objects does not seem to be a concern on that platform at least.

```
1: PASS
hashref: PASS
arrayref: PASS
globref: PASS
in-memory: PASS
FH1 glob: PASS
FH2 globref: PASS
FH3 string: PASS
STDIN glob: PASS
plain read: PASS
plain write: PASS
FH read: PASS
FH write: PASS
I::F read: PASS
I::F write: PASS
pipe read: PASS
pipe write: PASS
FIFO read: PASS
socket: PASS
```

Comment: It looks like `tell` is not portable and fails to detect valid things: "The return value of tell() for the standard streams like the STDIN depends on the operating system: it may return -1 or something else. tell() on pipes, fifos, and sockets usually returns -1."

Comment: Really cool.  Makes me wonder why there isn't something like this on CPAN already.

Comment: @Robert P, there is.  It's called [openhandle in Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil#openhandle).  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214647/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-scalar-holds-a-filehandle/3807592#3807592).

Comment: It looks like `openhandle` fails the "FH3 string" test, but that could arguably be the correct response.

Answer (score 5):

But *any* scalar contains something that could be used as a filehandle.  Strings can be filehandles: they are package handles, then.

We always used to use `Symbol::qualify()` for this. I don’t know whether that’s still “the” way that’s commonly advocated, but it will work if you are passed bareword handles (which are just strings).   It checks the `caller`’s package, qualifying it appropriately.
here’s also `Symbol::qualify_to_ref()`, which may perhaps be closer to what you’re looking for.

Here's how they both work. In the output below:

1. The first item in the => list is what gets made by `qualify`
2. The second item in the => list is what gets made by `qualify_to_ref`
3. The third item in the => list is file `fileno` returns on the second item

The script that produces this is included below:

```
off to NotMain
 string    "stderr"       => main::stderr, GLOB(0x811720), fileno 2
 string    *stderr        => *NotMain::stderr, GLOB(0x879ec0), fileno undef
 string    *sneeze        => *NotMain::sneeze, GLOB(0x811e90), fileno undef
 string    *STDERR        => *main::STDERR, GLOB(0x835260), fileno 2
back to main
 string    *stderr        => *main::stderr, GLOB(0x879ec0), fileno 2
 string    "STDOUT"       => main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x8116c0), fileno 1
 string    *STDOUT        => *main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x811e90), fileno 1
 string    *STDOUT{IO}    => IO::File=IO(0x8116d0), GLOB(0x811e90), fileno 1
 string   \*STDOUT        => GLOB(0x8116c0), GLOB(0x8116c0), fileno 1
 string   "sneezy"        => main::sneezy, GLOB(0x879ec0), fileno undef
 string   "hard to type"  => main::hard to type, GLOB(0x8039e0), fileno 3
 string   $new_fh         => IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8046c0), IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8046c0), fileno undef
 string   "GLOBAL"        => main::GLOBAL, GLOB(0x891ff0), fileno 3
 string   *GLOBAL         => *main::GLOBAL, GLOB(0x835260), fileno 3
 string   $GLOBAL         => main::/dev/null, GLOB(0x817320), fileno 3
 string   $null           => GLOB(0x8907d0), GLOB(0x8907d0), fileno 4

off to NotMain
   glob    "stderr"       => main::stderr, GLOB(0x811720), fileno 2
   glob     stderr        => main::stderr, GLOB(0x811720), fileno 2
   glob     sneeze        => main::sneeze, GLOB(0x81e490), fileno undef
   glob    *sneeze        => GLOB(0x892b90), GLOB(0x892b90), fileno undef
   glob    *stderr        => GLOB(0x892710), GLOB(0x892710), fileno undef
   glob    *STDERR        => GLOB(0x811700), GLOB(0x811700), fileno 2
back to main
   glob    *stderr        => GLOB(0x811720), GLOB(0x811720), fileno 2
   glob     STDOUT        => main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x8116c0), fileno 1
   glob    "STDOUT"       => main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x8116c0), fileno 1
   glob    *STDOUT        => GLOB(0x8116c0), GLOB(0x8116c0), fileno 1
   glob    *STDOUT{IO}    => IO::File=IO(0x8116d0), GLOB(0x811d50), fileno 1
   glob   \*STDOUT        => GLOB(0x8116c0), GLOB(0x8116c0), fileno 1
   glob    sneezy         => main::sneezy, GLOB(0x879ec0), fileno undef
   glob   "sneezy"        => main::sneezy, GLOB(0x879ec0), fileno undef
   glob   "hard to type"  => main::hard to type, GLOB(0x8039e0), fileno 3
   glob   $new_fh         => IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8046c0), IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8046c0), fileno undef
   glob    GLOBAL         => main::GLOBAL, GLOB(0x891ff0), fileno 3
   glob   $GLOBAL         => main::/dev/null, GLOB(0x817320), fileno 3
   glob   *GLOBAL         => GLOB(0x891ff0), GLOB(0x891ff0), fileno 3
   glob   $null           => GLOB(0x8907d0), GLOB(0x8907d0), fileno 4
```

And here’s the script that generate that output:

```
eval 'exec perl $0 ${1+"$@"}'
               if 0;

use 5.010_000;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings qw[ FATAL all ];

use Symbol;
use IO::Handle;

#define exec(arg)
BEGIN { exec("cpp $0 | $^X") }  # nyah nyah nyah-NYAH nhah!!
#undef  exec

#define CPP(FN, ARG) printf(" %6s %s => %s\n", main::short("FN"), q(ARG), FN(ARG))
#define QS(ARG)      CPP(main::qual_string, ARG)
#define QG(ARG)      CPP(main::qual_glob, ARG)
#define NL           say ""

sub comma(@);
sub short($);
sub qual($);
sub qual_glob(*);
sub qual_string($);

$| = 1;

main();
exit();

sub main {

    our $GLOBAL = "/dev/null";
    open GLOBAL;

    my $new_fh = new IO::Handle;

    open(my $null, "/dev/null");

    for my $str ($GLOBAL, "hard to type") {
        no strict "refs";
        *$str = *GLOBAL{IO};
    }

    fake_qs();

    QS(  *stderr       );
    QS(  "STDOUT"      );
    QS(  *STDOUT       );
    QS(  *STDOUT{IO}   );
    QS( \*STDOUT       );
    QS( "sneezy"       );
    QS( "hard to type" );
    QS( $new_fh        );
    QS( "GLOBAL"       );
    QS( *GLOBAL        );
    QS( $GLOBAL        );
    QS( $null          );

    NL;

    fake_qg();

    QG(  *stderr       );
    QG(   STDOUT       );
    QG(  "STDOUT"      );
    QG(  *STDOUT       );
    QG(  *STDOUT{IO}   );
    QG( \*STDOUT       );
    QG(  sneezy        );
    QG( "sneezy"       );
    QG( "hard to type" );
    QG( $new_fh        );
    QG(  GLOBAL        );
    QG( $GLOBAL        );
    QG( *GLOBAL        );
    QG( $null          );

    NL;

}

package main;

sub comma(@) { join(", " => @_) }

sub qual_string($) {
    my $string = shift();
    return qual($string);
}

sub qual_glob(*) {
    my $handle = shift();
    return qual($handle);
}

sub qual($) {
    my $thingie = shift();

    my $qname = qualify($thingie);
    my $qref  = qualify_to_ref($thingie);
    my $fnum  = do { no autodie; fileno($qref) };
    $fnum = "undef" unless defined $fnum;

    return comma($qname, $qref, "fileno $fnum");
}

sub short($) {
    my $name = shift();
    $name =~ s/.*_//;
    return $name;
}


sub fake_qg { &NotMain::fake_qg }
sub fake_qs { &NotMain::fake_qs }

package NotMain;  # this is just wicked

sub fake_qg {
    say "off to NotMain";
    QG(  "stderr"      );
    QG(   stderr       );
    QG(   sneeze       );
    QG(  *sneeze       );
    QG(  *stderr       );
    QG(  *STDERR       );
    say "back to main";
}

sub fake_qs {
    say "off to NotMain";
    package NotMain;
    QS(  "stderr"      );
    QS(  *stderr       );
    QS(  *sneeze       );
    QS(  *STDERR       );
    say "back to main";
}
```

What can I say?  Sometimes I really miss the C preprocessor.

I just *know* this one’s gonna get me talked about. ☺

Comment: Hey look, that stupid windbag otherwise known as `perlcritic` doesn’t even kvetch upon unary `open`.  Shows what *they* know!

Answer (score 3):

[`io_from_any` from `IO::Handle::Util`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle%3a%3aUtil) takes care of upgrading anything to something sane.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excerpt from [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Copy) determining whether or not a variable is a file handle:

```
my $from_a_handle = (ref($from)
  ? (ref($from) eq 'GLOB'
      || UNIVERSAL::isa($from, 'GLOB')
      || UNIVERSAL::isa($from, 'IO::Handle'))
  : (ref(\$from) eq 'GLOB'));
```

Comment: Eww.  `UNIVERSAL::isa` is a bad bad bad way of doing isa.  I'd prefer `eval { $from->isa('GLOB') }` so that inheritance and overriding work correctly.  So sayeth [the isa documentation.](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.1/lib/UNIVERSAL.pm).  I mean, the example they give for what NOT to do is `$is_io    = UNIVERSAL::isa($fd, "IO::Handle"); # BAD!`

Comment: @Robert P: Actually for GLOB (and other basic reference types) the latest recommendation is to use Scalar::Util::reftype(). While I agree somewhat with all this, using the above code will give you the same results as File::Copy, a core module, and you'd have to go through some effort to make it not work.

Comment: @Robert P: And I experienced a discussion of this on PerlMonks (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=615015) with no real conclusive answer for what is current best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use:

```
 eval { $fh->can('readline') }
```

Or can('print') in the case of handles I intend on writing to.  This is mostly because I really only want to deal with filehandles in an OO-way anyway, so this accurately resolves whether the target can do what I expect of it.  If you've already checked for the $fh being defined, you can probably leave off the eval.