# How can I test if I can write to a filehandle?

Tags: perl, file-io, filehandle

I have some subroutines that I call like this `myWrite($fileName, \@data)`.  `myWrite()` opens the file and writes out the data in some way.  I want to modify `myWrite` so that I can call it as above *or* with a filehandle as the first argument.  (The main reason for this modification is to delegate the opening of the file to the calling script rather than the module.  If there is a better solution for how to tell an IO subroutine where to write, i'd be glad to hear it.)

In order to do this, I must test whether the first input var is a filehandle.  I figured out how to do that by reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214647/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-scalar-holds-a-filehandle).

**Now here's my question**: I also want to test whether I can write to this filehandle.  I can't figure out how to do that.

Here's what I want to do:

```
sub myWrite {
  my ($writeTo, $data) = @_;
  my $fh;
  if (isFilehandle($writeTo)) { # i can do this
    die "you're an immoral person\n" 
      unless (canWriteTo($writeTo)); # but how do I do this?
    $fh = $writeTo;
  } else {
    open $fh, ">", $writeTo;
  }
  ...
}
```

All I need to know is if I can write to the filehandle, though it would be nice to see some general solution that tells you whether you're filehandle was opened with ">>" or "<", or if it isn't open, etc.

(Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520196/how-can-i-check-if-a-filehandle-is-open-in-perl) is related but doesn't seem to answer my question.)

Comment: Be aware that the answers to [that question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214647/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-scalar-holds-a-filehandle) had overlooked the [openhandle function in Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util#openhandle).

Comment: Why not document your module well that the caller needs to hand you a legit writeable handle and die or handle the error gracefully if the handle passed is not writeable? Am I missing something?

Comment: @drewk die under what circumstances?  identify the error how?

Comment: If you try writing to a file handle that is read only, you will get an error. Trap the error. What is the caller going to do in his context with your error? Die, warn, fix the bug. Even if you know that you have a file handle that you cannot write to, it seems you only have 3 options: 1) return a failure indicator, 2) die, 3) warn. You cannot convert the file handle. What will your program do with the information even if you can get it reliably?

Comment: @drewk I guess I don't know generally how to "trap the error" (`eval`? `or die/return $error/etc`?), hence my question.  i appreciate your help.

Comment: @flies: I posted an answer with an example.

Comment: @flies: for trapping errors, search for `[perl] [exception]` on this site -- there are some excellent discussions comparing the various options available.

Comment: The referenced code does **not** reliably determine whether a scalar value holds a filehandle!!

Comment: @tchrist: which referenced code?  There were many answers (I am partial to `openhandle FH` from [Scalar::Util](http://p3rl.org/Scalar::Util))

Comment: @tchrist Well then comment on those answers or post one that does. Broken? Fix it!

Comment: @Schwern: so many bugs, so little time.  The right way involves checking whether `fileno(Symbol::qualify_to_ref($might_be_handle))` returns a valid integer instead of `undef`.

Comment: The `-r` and `-w` operators tell you about whether the read and write *file permissions* are enabled on a file for the current user. They do not tell you anything whether the filehandles that have opened those files are for reading or writing.

Comment: @Jakub: What Perl version?  It’s not in v5.12, or so it seems.

Comment: @tchrist: Are we talking about `openhandle FH` from Scalar::Util?  It is in Scalar::Util 1.14 from Perl 5.8.6 (Scalar::Util is in core since Perl 5.8.1 at least).

Comment: @Jakub: Its manpage doesn’t list it in the SYNOPSIS. Lame!  Anyway, that code is *wrong*: `open(NULL, "/dev/null") || die; printf "handle is %d, openhandle is %s\n", fileno(NULL), openhandle("NULL") ? "ok" : "stupid and wrong";` => **handle is 3, openhandle is stupid and wrong**. I *told* you that you have to use `Symbol::qualify` or `Symbol::qualify_to_ref`!!  We’ve known the right way to do this *for 20 years now*. I can’t believe people still write broken code like this and tell others to use it.

Comment: Note that ` perl -Mstrict -Mautodie -MIO::Handle -le 'our $NULL = "/dev/null"; open NULL; print NULL->fileno`  correctly returns 3.

Comment: tchrist, you made a mistake. `openhandle(*NULL)` works just fine.

Comment: @daxim: I made no mistake.  Look at my code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Detecting Openness of Handles

As Axeman points out, `$handle->opened()` tells you whether it is open.

```
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings qw< FATAL all >;
use IO::Handle;
use Scalar::Util qw< openhandle >;

our $NULL = "/dev/null";
open NULL;
printf "NULL is %sopened.\n", NULL->opened() ? "" : "not ";
printf "NULL is %sopenhandled.\n", openhandle("NULL") ? "" : "not ";
printf "NULL is fd %d.\n", fileno(NULL);
```

produces

```
NULL is opened.
NULL is not openhandled.
NULL is fd 3.
```

As you see, you cannot use `Scalar::Util::openhandle()`, because it is just too stupid and buggy.

### Open Handle Stress Test

The correct approach, **if** you were not using `IO::Handle->opened`, is demonstrated in the following simple little trilingual script:

```
eval 'exec perl $0 ${1+"$@"}'
               if 0;

use 5.010_000;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings qw[ FATAL all ];

use Symbol;
use IO::Handle;

#define exec(arg)
BEGIN { exec("cpp $0 | $^X") } #!/usr/bin/perl -P
#undef  exec

#define SAY(FN, ARG) printf("%6s %s => %s\n", short("FN"), q(ARG), FN(ARG))
#define STRING(ARG)  SAY(qual_string, ARG)
#define GLOB(ARG)    SAY(qual_glob, ARG)
#define NL           say ""
#define TOUGH        "hard!to!type"

sub comma(@);
sub short($);
sub qual($);
sub qual_glob(*);
sub qual_string($);

$| = 1;

main();
exit();

sub main { 

    our $GLOBAL = "/dev/null";
    open GLOBAL;

    my $new_fh = new IO::Handle;

    open(my $null, $GLOBAL);

    for my $str ($GLOBAL, TOUGH) {
        no strict "refs";
        *$str = *GLOBAL{IO};
    }

    STRING(  *stderr       );
    STRING(  "STDOUT"      );
    STRING(  *STDOUT       );
    STRING(  *STDOUT{IO}   );
    STRING( \*STDOUT       );
    STRING( "sneezy"       );
    STRING( TOUGH );
    STRING( $new_fh        );
    STRING( "GLOBAL"       );
    STRING( *GLOBAL        );
    STRING( $GLOBAL        );
    STRING( $null          );

    NL;

    GLOB(  *stderr       );
    GLOB(   STDOUT       );
    GLOB(  "STDOUT"      );
    GLOB(  *STDOUT       );
    GLOB(  *STDOUT{IO}   );
    GLOB( \*STDOUT       );
    GLOB(  sneezy        );
    GLOB( "sneezy"       );
    GLOB( TOUGH );
    GLOB( $new_fh        );
    GLOB(  GLOBAL        );
    GLOB( $GLOBAL        );
    GLOB( *GLOBAL        );
    GLOB( $null          );

    NL;

}

sub comma(@) { join(", " => @_) }

sub qual_string($) { 
    my $string = shift();
    return qual($string);
} 

sub qual_glob(*) { 
    my $handle = shift();
    return qual($handle);
} 

sub qual($) {
    my $thingie = shift();

    my $qname = qualify($thingie);
    my $qref  = qualify_to_ref($thingie); 
    my $fnum  = do { no autodie; fileno($qref) };
    $fnum = "undef" unless defined $fnum;

    return comma($qname, $qref, "fileno $fnum");
} 

sub short($) {
    my $name = shift();
    $name =~ s/.*_//;
    return $name;
}
```

Which when run produces:

```
string    *stderr        => *main::stderr, GLOB(0x8368f7b0), fileno 2
string    "STDOUT"       => main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x8868ffd0), fileno 1
string    *STDOUT        => *main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x84ef4750), fileno 1
string    *STDOUT{IO}    => IO::Handle=IO(0x8868ffe0), GLOB(0x84ef4750), fileno 1
string   \*STDOUT        => GLOB(0x8868ffd0), GLOB(0x8868ffd0), fileno 1
string   "sneezy"        => main::sneezy, GLOB(0x84169f10), fileno undef
string   "hard!to!type"  => main::hard!to!type, GLOB(0x8868f1d0), fileno 3
string   $new_fh         => IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8868f0b0), IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8868f0b0), fileno undef
string   "GLOBAL"        => main::GLOBAL, GLOB(0x899a4840), fileno 3
string   *GLOBAL         => *main::GLOBAL, GLOB(0x84ef4630), fileno 3
string   $GLOBAL         => main::/dev/null, GLOB(0x7f20ec00), fileno 3
string   $null           => GLOB(0x86f69bb0), GLOB(0x86f69bb0), fileno 4

  glob    *stderr        => GLOB(0x84ef4050), GLOB(0x84ef4050), fileno 2
  glob     STDOUT        => main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x8868ffd0), fileno 1
  glob    "STDOUT"       => main::STDOUT, GLOB(0x8868ffd0), fileno 1
  glob    *STDOUT        => GLOB(0x8868ffd0), GLOB(0x8868ffd0), fileno 1
  glob    *STDOUT{IO}    => IO::Handle=IO(0x8868ffe0), GLOB(0x84ef4630), fileno 1
  glob   \*STDOUT        => GLOB(0x8868ffd0), GLOB(0x8868ffd0), fileno 1
  glob    sneezy         => main::sneezy, GLOB(0x84169f10), fileno undef
  glob   "sneezy"        => main::sneezy, GLOB(0x84169f10), fileno undef
  glob   "hard!to!type"  => main::hard!to!type, GLOB(0x8868f1d0), fileno 3
  glob   $new_fh         => IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8868f0b0), IO::Handle=GLOB(0x8868f0b0), fileno undef
  glob    GLOBAL         => main::GLOBAL, GLOB(0x899a4840), fileno 3
  glob   $GLOBAL         => main::/dev/null, GLOB(0x7f20ec00), fileno 3
  glob   *GLOBAL         => GLOB(0x899a4840), GLOB(0x899a4840), fileno 3
  glob   $null           => GLOB(0x86f69bb0), GLOB(0x86f69bb0), fileno 4
```

*That* is how you test for open file handles!

But that wasn’t even your question, I believe.

Still, I felt it needed addressing, as there are too many incorrect solutions to that problem floating around here. People need to open their eyes to how these things actually work.  Note that the two functions from `Symbol` use the `caller`’s package if necessary—which it certainly often is.

### Determining Read/Write Mode of Open Handle

*This* is the answer to your question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings qw< FATAL all >;

use Fcntl;

my (%flags, @fh);
my $DEVICE  = "/dev/null";
my @F_MODES = map { $_ => "+$_" } qw[ < > >> ];
my @O_MODES = map { $_ | O_WRONLY }
        O_SYNC                          ,
                 O_NONBLOCK             ,
        O_SYNC              | O_APPEND  ,
                 O_NONBLOCK | O_APPEND  ,
        O_SYNC | O_NONBLOCK | O_APPEND  ,
    ;

   open($fh[++$#fh], $_, $DEVICE) for @F_MODES;
sysopen($fh[++$#fh], $DEVICE, $_) for @O_MODES;

eval { $flags{$_} = main->$_ } for grep /^O_/, keys %::;

for my $fh (@fh) {
    printf("fd %2d: " => fileno($fh));
    my ($flags => @flags) = 0+fcntl($fh, F_GETFL, my $junk);
    while (my($_, $flag) = each %flags) {
        next if $flag == O_ACCMODE;
        push @flags => /O_(.*)/ if $flags & $flag;
    }
    push @flags => "RDONLY" unless $flags & O_ACCMODE;
    printf("%s\n",  join(", " => map{lc}@flags));
}

close $_ for reverse STDOUT => @fh;
```

Which, when run, produces this output:

```
fd  3: rdonly
fd  4: rdwr
fd  5: wronly
fd  6: rdwr
fd  7: wronly, append
fd  8: rdwr, append
fd  9: wronly, sync
fd 10: ndelay, wronly, nonblock
fd 11: wronly, sync, append
fd 12: ndelay, wronly, nonblock, append
fd 13: ndelay, wronly, nonblock, sync, append
```

Happy now, Schwern? ☺

Comment: Yes.  Did you know Stack Overflow sends 10% of every comment to starving children on the Moon?  So please, be sure to never leave less than 15 characters in your comment.  Think of the Mooninites.

Comment: What this line is for, and what it does: `eval { $flags{$_} = main->$_ } for grep /^O_/, keys %::;`

Comment: @Jakub it figures out what all the O_* flags names and numbers are for the current system, and makes a hash of them.

Comment: `%::` (`%main::`) is main symbol table, and `main->$_` is to avoid calling subroutine (that's what [constants](http://p3rl.org/constant) are in Perl) by name (which would require `no strict 'refs';`, isn't it?  Do I understand it correctly?  Nice trick!

Answer (score 8):

Still experimenting with this, but maybe you can try a zero-byte syswrite to a filehandle and check for errors:

```
open A, '<', '/some/file';
open B, '>', '/some/other-file';

{
    local $! = 0;
    my $n = syswrite A, "";
    # result: $n is undef, $! is "Bad file descriptor"
}
{
    local $! = 0;
    my $n = syswrite B, "";
    # result: $n is 0, $! is ""
}
```

[`fcntl`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#fcntl) looks promising too. Your mileage may vary, but something like this could be on the right track:

```
use Fcntl;
$flags = fcntl HANDLE, F_GETFL, 0;  # "GET FLags"
if (  ($flags & O_ACCMODE) & (O_WRONLY|O_RDWR) ) {
    print "HANDLE is writeable ...\n"
}
```

Comment: fcntl seems to be the solution i was after, though it reminds me why i was never a fan of C.

Comment: This really ought to be an API on IO::Handle.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [`IO`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO) (and you should), then `$handle->opened` will tell you whether a handle is *opened*. Might have to delve deeper to tell its mode.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to reinvent exception handling. Don't do that. There are lots of potential errors besides being handed a write-only handle. How about being handed a closed handle? A handle with an existing error?

mobrule's method with `use Fcntl;` correctly determines the flags on a filehandle, but this does not generally handle errors and warnings.

If you want to delegate to the caller the responsibility of opening the file, delegate to the caller the appropriate handling of exceptions. This allows the caller to choose the appropriate response. The vast majority of times, it will be either to die or warn or fix the offending code that handed you a bad handle.

There are two way to handle exceptions on a file handle passed to you.

First, if you can look at [TryCatch](http://search.cpan.org/~ash/TryCatch-1.002000/lib/TryCatch.pm) or [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~nuffin/Try-Tiny-0.06/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) on CPAN and use that method of exception handling. I use TryCatch and it is great.

A second method is use [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) and catch the appropriate error or warning after the eval is finished.

If you attempt to write to a read-only file handle, it is a warning that is generated. Catch the warning that is generated from your attempted write and you can then return success or failure to the caller.

Here is an example:

```
use strict; use warnings;

sub perr {
    my $fh=shift;
    my $text=shift;
    my ($package, $file, $line, $sub)=caller(0);
    my $oldwarn=$SIG{__WARN__};
    my $perr_error;

    {
        local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { 
            my $dad=(caller(1))[3];
            if ($dad eq "(eval)" ) {
                $perr_error=$_[0];
                return ;
            }   
            oldwarn->(@_);
        };
        eval { print $fh $text }; 
    }    

    if(defined $perr_error) {
        my $s="$sub, line: $line";
        $perr_error=~s/line \d+\./$s/ ;
        warn "$sub called in void context with warning:\n" .  
             $perr_error 
             if(!defined wantarray);
        return wantarray ? (0,$perr_error) : 0;
    }
    return wantarray ? (1,"") : 1;
}

my $fh;
my @result;
my $res;
my $fname="blah blah file";

open $fh, '>', $fname;

print "\n\n","Successful write\n\n" 
     if perr $fh, "opened by Perl and writen to...\n";

close $fh;

open $fh, '<', $fname;

# void context:
perr $fh, "try writing to a read-only handle";

# scalar context:
$res=perr $fh, "try writing to a read-only handle";


@result=perr $fh, "try writing to a read-only handle";
if  ($result[0]) {
   print "SUCCESS!!\n\n";
} else {
    print "\n","I dunno -- should I die or warn this:\n";
    print $result[1];
}   

close $fh;
@result=perr $fh, "try writing to a closed handle";
if  ($result[0]) {
   print "SUCCESS!!\n\n";
} else {
    print "\n","I dunno -- should I die or warn this:\n";
    print $result[1];
}
```

The output:

```
Successful write

main::perr called in void context with warning:
Filehandle $fh opened only for input at ./perr.pl main::perr, line: 49

I dunno -- should I die or warn this:
Filehandle $fh opened only for input at ./perr.pl main::perr, line: 55

I dunno -- should I die or warn this:
print() on closed filehandle $fh at ./perr.pl main::perr, line: 64
```

Comment: Most modern people prefer `Try::Tiny` to `TryCatch`.  Consider that.

Comment: @Randal Schwartz: I will try Try::Tiny. I think you still have to redirect $SIG{__WARN__} for TryCatch though. Does either "catch" on warnings alone? I guess I could try it....

Comment: @Randal Schwartz: I did try Try::Tiny. It does not catch warnings. Only fatal errors.

Comment: Try::Tiny is small and elegant, but it doesn't allow catching various types of exceptions with type constraints like TryCatch does -- both have uses in Modern Perl.

Comment: TryCatch is broken since Devel::Declare on which it relies is dead. Use [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) which does a real and full implementation of try-catch block like in other programming languages, including with catch, variable assignment and finally.

Answer (score 1):

The -w operator can be used to test whether a file **or a filehandle** is writeable

```
open my $fhr, '<', '/etc/passwd' or die "$!";
printf("%s read from fhr\n", -r $fhr ? 'Can' : "Can't");
printf("%s write to fhr\n",  -w $fhr ? 'Can' : "Can't");

open my $fhw, '>', '/tmp/test' or die "$!";
printf("%s read from fhw\n", -r $fhw ? 'Can' : "Can't");
printf("%s write to fhw\n",  -w $fhw ? 'Can' : "Can't");
```

Output:

```
Can read from fhr
Can't write to fhr
Can read from fhw
Can write to fhw
```

Comment: Not sure that this is right. I think this just tests whether the filehandle has opened a writeable file, not whether the filehandle itself is writeable.  Try your first example with a file you have permission to write.

Comment: mobrule is correct.  `-w` tests whether the _file_ to which a filehandle is open is writable, not whether the filehandle has been opened in write mode.

Comment: Well that explains why the second filehandle appears to be readable (despite only being opened in write mode) which I must admit did strike me as odd.