# How to check in Perl if filehandle is opened for reading or for writing?

Tags: perl, filehandle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I test if I can write to a filehandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807231/how-can-i-test-if-i-can-write-to-a-filehandle)

Now that [I found how to check in Perl if given scalar variable holds a filehandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214647/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-scalar-holds-a-filehandle), is it possible to check if the filehandle was opened for reading, or was opened for writing?  And if it is, then how to check it?

The [-r and -w](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) operators works, from what I understand, only on filehandles opened to real files, and not e.g. pipes, in-memory files (opening to scalar), etc.