# How do I find out if the value of a variable in Perl is a scalar or an array?

Tags: perl

Say I have this:

```
my %hash;

$hash{"a"} = "abc";
$hash{"b"} = [1, 2, 3];
```

How can I, later on, find out if what was stored was a scalar, like in `"abc"`, or an array, like in `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell what type of value is in a Perl variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731333/how-do-i-tell-what-type-of-value-is-in-a-perl-variable)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, your example of an array reference is wrong - your `$hash{"b"}` will end up with a **scalar value**: the last element of the list you provided ('c' in this case).

That said, if you actually do want to see if you have a scalar or a reference, use the `ref` function:

```
my %hash;

$hash{"a"} = "abc";
$hash{"b"} = [qw/a b c/];

if (ref $hash{"b"} eq 'ARRAY') {
  print "it's an array reference!";
}
```

**Docs**

- Documentation for the ref function:  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html

Comment: Note that, in the OP's code, `$hash{b}` ends up being `'c'` rather than `['a', 'b', 'c']` as he wants (or 3 as I initially expected it to).

Comment: Silly mistake -- bad copy&paste from somewhere else just to get some simple code for the question.

Answer (score 8):

First off, `$hash{"b"} = qw/a b c/;` will store `'c'` in `$hash{"b"}`, not an array, you may have meant `$hash{"b"} = [ qw/a b c/ ];`  which will store a reference to an array in to `$hash{"b"}`.  This is the key bit of information.  Anything other than a scalar must be stored as a reference when assigned to a scalar.  There is a function named [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) that will tell you information about a reference, but it will hand you the name of the object's class if the reference has been blessed.  Happily there is another function named `reftype` that always returns they type of the structure in [`Scalar::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw/reftype/;

my $rs  = \4;
my $ra  = [1 .. 5];
my $rh  = { a => 1 };
my $obj = bless {}, "UNIVERSAL";

print "ref: ", ref($rs), " reftype: ", reftype($rs), "\n",
    "ref: ", ref($ra), " reftype: ", reftype($ra), "\n",
    "ref: ", ref($rh), " reftype: ", reftype($rh), "\n",
    "ref: ", ref($obj), " reftype: ", reftype($obj), "\n";
```

Comment: What strikes me as being odd is [why `ref $fileHandle` doesn't return 'IO'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955428/when-does-refvariable-return-io)

Comment: @Zaid They could have done that, but then all of the legacy code that expects a typeglob would have broken with the new lexical filehandles.  Perl 5 has always strived to not break existing code; you can understand many of the odd choices when you keep that in mind.