# Scalar::Util vs. ref function

Tags: perl, perl-module

What's the difference between the built in `ref($object)` and `Scalar::Util` `blessed($object)`? Is one preferred over the other?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(blessed isvstring);

my $object = foo->new();

print "Object is a " . blessed($object) . "\n";
print "Object is a " . ref($object) . "\n";

my $version = 5.00.03;

print "Version is a " . ref(\$version) . "\n";
if (isvstring($version)) {
    print "Version is a VSTRING\n";
}

package foo;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};

    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399833/how-can-i-get-perls-ref-function-to-return-ref-io-and-lvalue/1400176#1400176

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to POD, `blessed()` only works on blessed references (e.g. a references passed to a `bless()` call).

It returns `undef` on everything else, including hash/array refs where `ref()` returns `HASH`/`ARRAY` (and a bunch of other types as delineated in [perldoc ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html)). To get reference type you can, of course call `Scalar::Util::reftype`.

As for whether one should be used over another, I think it depends largely on what the logic is.

- If you **only** want to distinguish real blessed references from everything else, `blessed()` provides a more concise way than taking a `ref` and then verifying that the value is not on of standard ones returned by unblessed reference.

  ```
  my $ref_type = ref($my_ref);
  print "USING REF: ";
  if (      $ref_type
         && $ref_type ne ref({})
         && $ref_type ne ref([])
         && $ref_type ne "SCALAR"
         # Could also use a hash with all allowed values of ref() instead
         && $ref_type !~ /^(CODE|REF|GLOB|...)$) { 
      print "I am an object of class $ref_type\n";
  } else {
      print "I'm a reference of type $ref_type\n";
  }


  # vs... 


  print "USING SCALAR_UTIL: ";
  my $ref_type = blessed($my_ref);
  print $ref_type ? "I am an object of class $ref_type\n"
                  : "I am a reference of type " . reftype($my_ref) . "\n";
  ```
- If you need fine distinctions between both blessed references and different ublessed ones, then a single `ref()` call is more concise than a combination of `blessed` and `reftype`.
- One edge case where there's an actual functional difference between the two approaches, as noted in the comments by Eric Strom, is when someone creates a class which matches one of `ref()` [hardcoded values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) (e.g. `bless [], 'HASH'` - in which case they are either Way Dumb or Way Too Clever By Half).

  ```
  my $sssft = bless [], 'HASH'; # sssft = someone_should_suffer_for_this
  ref_description_using_ref($sssft);
  ref_description_using_scalar_util($sssft);


  # OUTPUT:
  USING REF: I'm a reference of type HASH
  USING SCALAR_UTIL: I am an object of class HASH
  ```

DISCLAIMER: Based on documentation, there should be no difference between the two when the argument is a reference blessed into a class (e.g. it returns class name). But I haven't checked "Scalar::Util" source to confirm.

Comment: And on the flipside, `Scalar::Util::reftype` returns the underlying reference type (e.g. `HASH` or `GLOB` or whatever) even if its argument is blessed. Basically `reftype` and `blessed` uncouple the two different things that the builtin `ref` tries to do.

Comment: there is nothing stoping someone from writing `bless [], 'HASH'` or other craziness which will cause errors if only using `ref`.  thats where `blessed` and `reftype` come in handy

Comment: @Eric Strom: Whether or not using `ref` causes errors depends on how naively one processes its output. `HASH=ARRAY(0x182a35c)` looks odd but you *can* correctly extract the class and reference type before going to break the kneecaps of the sociopath who named a class "HASH."

Comment: @Michael Carman => won't `ref` always just return `HASH`?  I thought the `HASH=ARRAY(0x12341234)` output is only when you stringify the reference in the absence of any string overloading.  I'm not sure if breaking kneecaps is a harsh enough punishment :)

Comment: @Eric Strom: Gah! You're right. I was thinking of stringified references. That said, I wonder if there are any twisted cases where fooling `ref` with something like `bless [], 'HASH'` would be useful, perhaps in combination with `tie`... *cue evil laughter*

Comment: @hobbs - correct re: `reftype`. I chose not to add that to the answer to avoid extra info that didn't seem very related to the question.

Comment: @Michael Carman - don't give those maniacs any ideas! *shudder*

Comment: @Eric - Since you didn't add this as a separate answer, I took the liberty to add your idea as part of mine. And now I want to break kneecaps.